# Update file after adding new object with JQ

Tags: shell, jq

I'm new in using `jq` library, Here i'm reading `HotelInfo` field of my json:

```
./jq-linux64 '.HotelInfo' 74687.json

{
  "HotelURL": "http://www.tripadvisor.com/aaa.html",
  "HotelID": "74687",
  "Price": "$156"
}
```

Now, i'm going to add `{city: tehran}` object to this array :

```
./jq-linux64 --arg city tehran '.HotelInfo +{city: $city}' 74687.json 

{
  "HotelURL": "http://www.tripadvisor.com/aaa.html",
  "HotelID": "74687",
  "Price": "$156",
  "city": "tehran"
}
```

And it's done, but this doesn't reflect on file too and file still not updated with this new record, How can i update the json file as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your original json structure and just append the new value you could use:

```
$ jq '.HotelInfo.city = "tehran"' 74687.json > 74687.jso.tmp
$ mv 74687.json.tmp 74687.json
```

This will update the file with all previous fields/objects if any:

```
{
  "HotelInfo": {
    "HotelURL": "http://www.tripadvisor.com/aaa.html",
    "HotelID": "74687",
    "Price": "$156",
    "city": "tehran"
  }
}
```

If you just want to create a new structure removing other possible keys within `.HotelInfo`

```
$ jq --arg city tehran '.HotelInfo +{city: $city}' 74687.json > 74687.jso.tmp 
$ mv 74687.json.tmp 74687.json
```

This will create the file with the `Hotelinfo` object contents only:

```
{
  "HotelURL": "http://www.tripadvisor.com/aaa.html",
  "HotelID": "74687",
  "Price": "$156",
  "city": "tehran"
}
```

Comment: why do you post this? I answered this already (30 min before your answer)

Comment: @hek2mgl your answer will create a new json within the scope of the child object and therefore lose all the parent objects, something probably OP would not like.

Comment: I still don't see the difference. Anyhow probably I'm missing something here

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the results to a temporary file and rename that to the original one:

```
./jq-linux64 --arg city tehran '.HotelInfo +{city: $city}' 74687.json > temp.json
mv temp.json 74687.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sponge` or write to a temporary file, and then "mv" it.

For further details and alternatives, see the following Q in the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ):

: How can "in-place" editing of a JSON file be accomplished? What is jq's equivalent of sed -i?

Comment: Hihi, nice to meet here again after our discussion on github yesterday :) (I'm metashock on github). Note that while sponge is nice, it is very likely not installed on a server system